# Ansible // iterate through variables in host_var files that have incrementing keys

Tags: automation, ansible

My use case is trying to write a playbook using the cisco.iosxr.iosxr_config module to update n ospf interface cost values on each host.  Some hosts have 2 interfaces, some have more. Is there a way to iterate through the variables in each host_var file whether there are 2 or 10 defined?

```
Task:
    - name: Adjust OSPF Cost of interfaces out of spec
      cisco.iosxr.iosxr_config:
        lines:
          - "interface {{OSPF_INT_1}} cost {{OSPF_INT_1_COST}}"
        parents: router ospf 1 area 0 
        replace: block
```

```
host_var file:

---
OSPF_INT_1: Bundle-Ether1.1
OSPF_INT_1_COST: 5801

OSPF_INT_2: Bundle-Ether1.2
OSPF_INT_2_COST: 5201

OSPF_INT_3: Bundle-Ether1.3
OSPF_INT_3_COST: 5201
```

Task as it stands works for implementing the settings for OSPF_INT_1, just can't quite figure out how to get the same task to run through the list. I did try just having separate tasks for each interface, but hosts that only have 2 interfaces will not have variables for OSPF_INT_3, OSPF_INT_n defined, so ansible errors out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For example, the project

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── host_vars
│   ├── host_1
│   ├── host_2
│   └── host_3
└── pb.yml
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/hosts
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host_1
host_2
host_3
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host_1
OSPF_INT_1: Bundle-Ether1.1
OSPF_INT_1_COST: 5801
OSPF_INT_2: Bundle-Ether1.2
OSPF_INT_2_COST: 5201
OSPF_INT_3: Bundle-Ether1.3
OSPF_INT_3_COST: 5201
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host_2
OSPF_INT_1: Bundle-Ether1.1
OSPF_INT_1_COST: 5801
OSPF_INT_2: Bundle-Ether1.2
OSPF_INT_2_COST: 5201
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host_3
OSPF_INT_1: Bundle-Ether1.1
OSPF_INT_1_COST: 5801
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars:

    intf: "{{ q('varnames', '^OSPF_INT_\\d+$') }}"
    cost: "{{ q('varnames', '^OSPF_INT_\\d+_COST$') }}"
    lines_str: |
      {% for i,c in intf|zip(cost) %}
      - interface {{ lookup('vars', i) }} cost {{ lookup('vars', c) }}
      {% endfor %}
    lines: "{{ lines_str|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          intf vars: {{ intf }}
          cost vars: {{ cost }}
    - debug:
        var: lines
```

gives limited to *host_1*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l host_1

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  msg: |-
    intf vars: ['OSPF_INT_1', 'OSPF_INT_2', 'OSPF_INT_3']
    cost vars: ['OSPF_INT_1_COST', 'OSPF_INT_2_COST', 'OSPF_INT_3_COST']

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  lines:
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.1 cost 5801
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.2 cost 5201
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.3 cost 5201

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host_1: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Running the playbook on all hosts gives abridged

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
...
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  lines:
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.1 cost 5801
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.2 cost 5201
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.3 cost 5201
ok: [host_2] => 
  lines:
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.1 cost 5801
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.2 cost 5201
ok: [host_3] => 
  lines:
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.1 cost 5801
```

---

Try (*shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --check --diff*) the task below if the above play gives you the correct lines

```yaml
   - name: Adjust OSPF Cost of interfaces out of spec
     cisco.iosxr.iosxr_config:
       lines: "{{ lines }}"
       parents: router ospf 1 area 0 
       replace: block
     when: lines|length > 0
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

---

Put the declarations into the *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all
intf: "{{ q('varnames', '^OSPF_INT_\\d+$') }}"
cost: "{{ q('varnames', '^OSPF_INT_\\d+_COST$') }}"
lines_str: |
  {% for i,c in intf|zip(cost) %}
  - interface {{ lookup('vars', i) }} cost {{ lookup('vars', c) }}
  {% endfor %}
lines: "{{ lines_str|from_yaml }}"
```

and make the playbook cleaner

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: lines
```

gives the same results

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_2] => 
  lines:
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.1 cost 5801
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.2 cost 5201
ok: [host_1] => 
  lines:
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.1 cost 5801
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.2 cost 5201
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.3 cost 5201
ok: [host_3] => 
  lines:
  - interface Bundle-Ether1.1 cost 5801

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host_1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_3: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case for the [`lookup("varnames", ...)`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/ansible/builtin/varnames_lookup.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-varnames-lookup) and then the handy [`with_together:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/ansible/builtin/together_lookup.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-together-lookup) to glue them back into matched pairs. Up to you if you would find `{{ vars[item.0] }}` more legible, or to send that var name list into [`|map("extract", vars)`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) to coerce them into `[interface, cost]` pairs

```yaml
  - name: just for testing
    set_fact:
      OSPF_INT_1: Bundle-Ether1.1
      OSPF_INT_1_COST: 5801

      OSPF_INT_2: Bundle-Ether1.2
      OSPF_INT_2_COST: 5201

      OSPF_INT_3: Bundle-Ether1.3
      OSPF_INT_3_COST: 5201

  - name: show the filtered items
    debug:
      msg: interface {{ item.0 }} cost {{ item.1 }}
    with_together:
    # the docs say lookup(varnames) returns a list[str]
    # but with ansible==7.1.0 it returned a CSV and thus required the split :-(
    - '{{ lookup("varnames", "OSPF_INT_[0-9]+$")      | split(",") | map("extract", vars) }}'
    - '{{ lookup("varnames", "OSPF_INT_[0-9]+_COST$") | split(",") | map("extract", vars) }}'
```

producing

```
TASK [show the filtered items] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Bundle-Ether1.1', 5801]) =>
  msg: interface Bundle-Ether1.1 cost 5801
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Bundle-Ether1.2', 5201]) =>
  msg: interface Bundle-Ether1.2 cost 5201
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Bundle-Ether1.3', 5201]) =>
  msg: interface Bundle-Ether1.3 cost 5201
```

Comment: Do not use the `vars` dict to access vars, it's an undocumented internal variable that is not intended to be used this way and does not behave the way people want it to. Use the `vars` lookup (and `query()` if you want a raw list instead of a comma-separated one.)  `query('vars', *query('varnames', 'OSPF_INT_[0-9]+$'))`